# Is the ordering of static members sensitive in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, singleton, static-members

I have this class, let's say, `Foo`. It `extends JFrame` and is a singleton. That being said, it has two **static fields**: 1) an instance of `Foo` and 2) a `Color`.

**Here's a code snippet of `Foo`:**

```
public class Foo extends JFrame{
    private static final Color FOO_RED = new Color(155, 64, 69);
    private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();

    private Foo(){
        //do stuff
    }

    public static Foo getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

I also have another class, let's say, `Launcher`. This is the **main class** that is responsible for launching the application. It's a simple class in that its only job is to delegate the task of constructing `Foo` to the `EDT`.

**Here's a code snippet of `Launcher`:**

```
public class Launcher{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater((new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Foo.getInstance();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Now, this all works just fine. **But**, when I switch the ordering of `Foo`'s fields (**See below**), the components that use `FOO_RED` are no longer painted this color.

```
public class Foo extends JFrame{
    private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo(); //declared before Color
    private static final Color FOO_RED = new Color(155, 64, 69);

    private Foo(){
        //do stuff
    }

    public static Foo getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

So, this begs the question, does the ordering of **static fields** matter when it comes to `Swing`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, ordering of static fields does matter. Executed in the order they appear.

I would make another change to this example. This would make you static field order less important.

UPDATE: Use [IDOH (Initialization on Demand Holder)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) pattern to make singleton thread safe.

```
private static class FooHolder {
    private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
}

public static Foo getInstance(){
    return FooHolder.INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: +1 for only initializing the instance when needed first time.

Comment: +1, explained why I was seeing the "quirky" behavior, and also provided a sound solution. thank you, basszero. :)

Comment: It's worth noting two things: @basszero You left the `INSTANCE` final (noted by Howard), and thus it cannot be assigned to twice (initialized to `null`). @mre This approach is _not_ thread safe. In this particular case, that is not an issue as you only use the method once, and always from the Event Thread (always the same thread). However, if another thread were to access it then it could potentially receive a different instance. It was worth noting to ensure you don't continue this form of "lazy initialization" throughout threaded code.

Comment: @pickypg Good catch and serves me right for being lazy. I typically use the IDOH pattern for my singletons.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. ordering matters for any `static` fields/blocks.

---

**EDIT**:
First, static fields are set to their default value(So `FOO_RED` is `null`).then the static fields are initialized in the order it appears. so it is possible to observe the `FOO_RED` field before it is initialized.

Comment: @mre And it's not specific to Swing.

Comment: so since `FOO_RED` is used in the construction of `Foo`, if I construct an instance of `Foo` BEFORE I declare `FOO_RED`, it won't use it? I'm a little confused about how if the ordering matters, why is there no compile-time error, or even run-time error.

Comment: @mre: first, static fields are set to their default value(FOO_RED is null).then the static fields are initialized in the order it appears. so it is possible to observe the FOO_RED field before it is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering does matter for static fields, as they are initialized from top to bottom. In your case, switching the order causes the Foo() constructor to be called before the initialization of FOO_RED. As such, FOO_RED will be `null` for use within the constructor. This is legal, though obviously of no use to any controls that would like to use FOO_RED.

Comment: that's strange. seems like there should be some "dependency" errors thrown (either compile-time, or run-time).

Comment: @mre Runtime I don't think would work, as it would have to "look ahead" to see that the field is used prior to initialization. I believe the compiler also doesn't catch it because it assumes all static initializers will run prior to any instance constructors. You've essentially "tricked" it by calling the Foo() constructor in a static initialization block. Checking for this case could become quite involved if it was a series of method calls that led to this, so it just ignores it and happily uses the null reference.